# Tomcat display deployed application name instead of war file

Tags: tomcat, logging

I have several applications deployed in tomcat 6 which are routed to different virtual hosts, so all of them have separate context roots and are named ROOT.war. When tomcat fires up, in catalina.out i see this:

```
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
Feb 11, 2011 1:33:55 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
Feb 11, 2011 1:33:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive ROOT.war
Feb 11, 2011 1:33:57 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
```

Application logs are routed to different location and I have no way of telling which applications were deployed and in what order.

I want to see application name from war's web.xml instead of ROOT.war. Does anyone know a way to do this without enabling debugging and cluttering the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tomcat does not support ordered webapp deployments (at least in versions 5-6) *de jure*. *De facto* you can put references to different webapps in desired order inside `conf/server.xml` and it will (likely) work. This however can be classified as a hack. The other disadvantage of this approach is that you have to statically define things in `server.xml`.

Another alternative would be to create a separate `DeploymentInfoLogger` (or whatever named) class inside each webapp having logger statically initialized with the name of this class. Enable debug level for this class only (so you don't get loads of unwanted log data). Configure appender to be the same as for `catalina.out` (`ConsoleAppender` I suppose?). Make this class a context listener and log something meaningful at the time of webapp startup. This is of course possible only if you know in advance that this webapp will be serving some particular virtual host. If not, you can probably use some native Tomcat API to determine this from configuration.

Sėkmės :)

Comment: I'm not concerned about the order which webapps are deployed in, just want to see a little bit more informative live data when restarting the server. It's not that critical to be worth the trouble writing a separate logger class for that. I guess there's no easy way, but thanks for an extensive answer! Ačiū :)